# Is readiness probe in kubernetes event after the POD is RUNNING state?

Tags: kubernetes

Is readiness probe run even after the POD is ready ? 
Will it run even after the POD is in RUNNING state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is readiness probe run even after the POD is ready ?

**Yes**

> Will it run even after the POD is in RUNNING state?

**Yes**

As [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes) is saying, there are some cases when:

> applications are temporarily unable to serve traffic... an application might depend on external services ... In such cases, you don't want to kill the application, but you don’t want to send it requests either. Kubernetes provides readiness probes to detect and mitigate these situations. A pod with containers reporting that they are not ready does not receive traffic through Kubernetes Services.

So, `liveness probe` is to detect and remedy situationswhen App cannot recover except by being restarted.

`Readiness probe` is used to detect situation when traffic shall not be sent to App.

Both probes have the same set of settings as `initialDelaySeconds`, `periodSeconds` , etc.

Answer (score 1):

Readiness probe checks if container available for incoming traffic. It is being constantly executed even when container gets ready.

Here are the docs:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/